# Dash - Cant get Markdown to appear above Graphs

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am in the finishing stages of my first real Plotly Dash dashboard. I have run into a problem where I can't add dcc.Markdown to any dcc.Graph elements.

It works fine with the dash.DataTable, as shown in the image below.

I am using Python v3.10, Dash v 2.6.2 & Plotly 5.10.

[image]

I tried to then use the same methodology to add markdown to the chart next to it, but this throws an error

> TypeError: The `dash_bootstrap_components.Col` component (version
> 1.2.1) with the ID "Graph(id='sun_burst1', figure={}, style={'height': '45vh'})" detected a Component for a prop other than `children` Prop
> id has value Graph(id='sun_burst1', figure={}, style={'height':
> '45vh'})

The DataTable is inside a Row and Col. The code is as follows. I haven't closed it below as it runs on for quite some time

```
dbc.Row(
        # Dash Data Table
        [dbc.Col(
            [dcc.Markdown('### Top Risks ###'),
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id='table1',
                columns=[
                    {'name': 'Risk ID', 'id': 'risk_id', 'type': 'text', 'editable': False},
```

Here is my erroneous code, Am I barking up the wrong Tree, does Markdown even work with dcc.Graph.

```
                dbc.Col(
                [dcc.Markdown('### Risk Breakdown ###'),
                dcc.Graph(id='sun_burst1', figure={}, style={'height': '45vh'}),
                width=4, lg={'size': 5, "offset": 0, 'order': 'second'}
                   ]),
```

I really am quite stumped.

My page is made up of 2 rows, top row with 3 columns of width 4, Bottom Row 2 x 6 columns.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. It is primarily a repetition of the tags and the word "issue", which is useless. Your title should be clear and descriptive about the problem you're having, and should convey meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results looking for a solution to a problem. See [ask] for more information about writing a good title.

Comment: Which Dash version do you have?

Comment: I have just updated the main post. I am using Dash 2.6.2, Python 3.10, and plotly 5.10.0

Comment: Please try to remove `dcc.Markdown('### Risk Breakdown ###')` from dbc.Col to see if the error still exists?

Comment: If I remove the reference to the dcc.Markdown then there is no error. My issue is I want to place Labels above the graphs using Markdown.

Comment: To address the problem, what happens if you replace `dcc.Graph` with any other dcc component, and what happens when you replace `dcc.Graph` with `dash_table.DataTable`?

Comment: If i put Datatable instead of Graph, it works as expected. My issue is I want to put descriptors above the graphs and lose the graph text

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple in the end. I had not taken into consideration where the 'children' ended.

I had the following which did not work. Note the terminating square bracket after the complete definition.

```
dbc.Col(
    [dcc.Markdown('#### Breakdown of Risk by Risk Type - 2021 ####'),
    dcc.Graph(id='sun_burst1', figure={}, style={'height': '40vh'})],
    width=4, lg={'size': 5, "offset": 0, 'order': 'second'}
        ]),
```

Ther solution is as follows. encase the 'children in square brackets and leave the other column definitions outside.

Solution:

```
dbc.Col(
    [dcc.Markdown('#### Breakdown of Risk by Risk Type - 2021 ####'),
    dcc.Graph(id='sun_burst1', figure={}, style={'height': '40vh'})],
    width=4, lg={'size': 5, "offset": 0, 'order': 'second'}
        ),
```

With this in place, I can now mark up my charts as I wish.

[image]

A big thank you to [jinnynor](https://community.plotly.com/u/jinnyzor) at Plotly community for provoking my thoughts